# FFmpeg stdout packet size for rawvideo

Tags: ffmpeg, size, stdout, packet

Is there a way to restrict/enforce packet size for rawvideo output over pipe?

```
ffmpeg -i video -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba -
```

So far I tried various arguments like `-video_size`, `-flush_packets`, `-chunk_size`, `-packetsize` and their combinations, but stdout keeps reading by 32768 bytes.

I would like to enforce each packet to contain a whole frame. Lets say 3686400 bytes (1280x720x4)
for my 1280x720 video, so I do not need to do additional buffering outside of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `-blocksize` is what you are looking for. [`pipe` protocol Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe).

That being said, it is default to INTMAX, so I suspect it's the invoker's pipe reader configuration which is limiting your transaction.

Comment: I believe you are correct, related configuration/setup is done likely by emscripten